# Questions about this expression

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-order

> We will pray to God for our life together in thankful mind on Sunday night.

The words in a preposition phrase are arranged one after another above.

As I see them, the word 'night' is a head and the word 'Sunday' is a specifier.

Therefore, instead of the preposition 'on', Does 'at' seem more suitable in the PP? Because I think the meaning of the preposition should be adapted for the head.

As far as I know, generally, 'At night' is a lot used in the sentences. Or differently, is something like some preposition omitted before the word 'night' in the sentence?

Comment: behind ; supporting a person, idea, etc

Answer (score 1):

We use "at night" to mean "during the hours of darkness".  But "On Sunday night" to mean "during a specific time span on a certain day".

This is idiomatic. There isn't any real logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

We say 'on Sunday' and we combine times and days with two prepositions: 'at three o'clock on Sunday'. In the case of 'on Sunday night' we're taking the single preposition from the day, not the time. The 'on' is "focused" on 'sunday', not 'night'.

Preposition choice often has no logic (in any language